# Recaptcha widget not closing and doing multiple valid callbacks

Tags: javascript, razor, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I have a page using multiple recaptcha's like this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
<script>
    var recaptchaElements = [];
</script>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   ...
<button class="g-recaptcha id="recaptcha-comment-form-button-@(item.Id)" type="button" value="comment">Submit</span></button>
   ...

<script>
    function @(functionId)submit(token) {
               ....
            }
    recaptchaElements.push({ id: "recaptcha-comment-form-button-@(item.Id)", callback : "@(functionId)submit" });
</script>
}
<script>
var recaptchaKey = "XXXX"
    var onloadCallback = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < recaptchaElements.length; i++) {
            grecaptcha.render(recaptchaElements[i].id, {
                'sitekey': recaptchaKey,
                'callback': recaptchaElements[i].callback,
                'theme': 'light'
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

I am creating a unique call back function for each of my recaptcha buttons because i need unique functionality for each. That is working.

The issue I have is that the recaptcha widget opens up when i click my buttons and then i select images to prove that I am not a robot. Once i select a few images it does the callback with a succesfull token and I verify the token with Google and it all works. The problem is that the widget for the image does not close. It remains open and as long as i continue selecting images it continues to fire my callback function so without knowing it the user is submitting the same callback multiple times.

How can i force the recaptcha widget to close in the callback function? Isn't it supposed to close automatically when the user is validated? Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?